# Cordova InAppBrowser not firing events

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am very new to cordova and facing some strange issue. I am using InAppBrowser to open a webpage, it's opening successfully, but the problem is it is not firing any events nor showing any error.
This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {   
        var ref = window.open(redirectURL, '_blank', 'EnableViewPortScale=yes');
        ref.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
            alert("in loadstop..");
            setTimeout(function() {
                win.close();
            }, 5000 );
        });
    }
```

This is my `config.xml`:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

I tried by adding this also:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

But still same issue and yes I have plugin in my plugins folder.

Basically I am not getting that alert ie "in loadstop". I searched lot of questions on SO but none of them have solved my issue. My Cordova version is `3.5.0-0.2.7` and I am trying to run it on Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3.

Don't understand what is the strange issue here, Can anyone please guide me? I am stuck here from many hours.

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap Build service, or building locally with Cordova-CLI?

Comment: I am using local cli

Comment: You need to remove the code from `config.xml` (that is only for phonegap build) and run `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser` and then `cordova build`

Comment: I added that plugin already !

Comment: Dear close voter and downvoter, please read the question correctly I have included all necessary details :) At-lease bother to leave a comment so I can improve question.

Comment: Having the same issue here, dunno how to solve it

Comment: I'm using cordova 5.4.1 now, and @DawsonLoudon's comment helped me in that for some reason(s) removing the in app browser plugin, re adding it, re building, then re running allowed the event to fire.